# Python webscraping doesn't produce raw HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping data from a table.

With the following code, instead of the raw HTML values being fetched, I am given the variable, so instead of getting the value in the table, I get `{value}`,

How can I get the raw HTML rather than the variable name?

Thanks

```
my_session = requests.session()
for_cookies = my_session.get("https://uk.investing.com")
cookies = for_cookies.cookies
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}
my_url = 'https://uk.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::4|sector::a|industry::80|equityType::a|exchange::3%3Ceq_market_cap;1'

response = my_session.get(my_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify()) # print the parsed data of html
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow!  I am not clear what the question is.  The `print` statement prints out HTML and I am not sure what is meant by `{value}`, since I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: When looking at the content of the table in the HTML, you'll see that most values come back as {value}. Did some reading. The reason for this is the page is dynamic, and it seems scraping for dynamic page is whole other ball game.

Comment: @onelostperson, For me, this printed out the html (like bartonstanley's did). Could you tell us if you did something differently, etc?